# How to get query parameters in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, parameters

I am using versions

```
"react": "^0.13.3",
"react-router": "^0.13.3"
```

i want to receive the params in which it navigate

1)Navigation done properly

2)what when i try to use `this.props.query.id` for receiving arguments it show `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
this.props.location.query.id
```

Comment: use `console.log('id', this.props.location.query.id)` inside render method, and check the result

Comment: done 1) this.transitionTo('template', null, {id: 10} );

Comment: Mayank Shukla can you plz tell me best way to use session and cookies in react.js

Comment: don't have much idea check this, may be help you: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4dw782/what_is_the_best_way_to_maintain_users_session_in/

Answer (score 5):

upgrade to react-router v4 and ;

Use this instead:

```
this.props.location.search
```

if you have a URL like `mysite.com/user/tweets?filter=top&origin=im`

Doing:

```
console.log(this.props.location.search); //yields "?filter=top&origin=im"
```

> Thus to get the value of "filter" or "origin", you need to use a
>   package for parsing query strings because react-router doesn’t come
>   with built-in support for parsing query strings. E.g. using
>   'query-string' library on NPM you can do:

```
import queryString from 'query-string';

const UrlQueryStrings = this.props.location.search;
const queryValues = queryString(UrlQueryStrings);

console.log(queryValues.filter); // Gives "top"
console.log(queryValues.origin); // Gives "im"
```

Comment: But how do you get the value for filter in this case?

Comment: @kabuto178 I have included how to get the values of the query parameters.

Comment: It should be queryString.parse(...)